# Breaking down a monolithic Java Jetty webservice application into microservices using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, microservices

I have a Java application which uses Jetty webservice and I want to break it down into microservices using Spring Boot framework. The monolithic application consists of several classes the main one are server, service and servlet.

I want to know if it's a good design if I put those three main modules (server, service, servlet) into 3 separate microservices.

```
public class ComedServer {
...

public static void main(String[] args){
...

Server server = new Server(14006);
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
andler.addServletWithMapping(ComedServlet.class,"/comedcsservices/*");
try {
 server.start();
 server.join();
} catch (Exception e)

}

}
```

---

```
public class ComedServelt extends HttpServlet {
...

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
...
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
...
  doPost(request, response);
...
}

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException,IOException {

...
}

public void destroy() {
LogManager.shutdown();
}
}
```

---

```
public class QueryComedProcessor {

public QueryComedProcessor(){...}

public QueryComedProcessor(RequestParameters reqParams,Properties propertiesFile) {
...

}

public String getQueryComedResponse(){...}
}
```

I want to use Spring Boot framework to create the microservices and I think I need to change the default embedded server for Spring Boot (Tomcat) to Jetty.

Comment: Moving from a monolith to microservices involves more than switching your launcher to Spring Boot.  You'll actually want to create separate projects for each of the services you define, and build relationships between them defined on the network protocols rather than on in-JVM interface calls.  I'd say that switching servlet containers is the least of your worries.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, going from embedded-jetty with 1 servlet to spring-boot isn't a change to use microservices, its just adding another layer on top of embedded-jetty.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt what would be the suggested way for this transformation? It's my first time breaking down an existing application into microservices, and I am still researching about this.